# How to process with AWS-cognito NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED Challenge

Tags: php, laravel, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-php-sdk

When I use the below code:

```
$result = $this->client->adminInitiateAuth([
                'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
                'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
                'UserPoolId' => $this->userpool_id,
                'AuthParameters' => [
                    'USERNAME' => $username,
                    'PASSWORD' => $password,
                ],
            ]);
```

I am getting a response with `session` and **`challengeName :NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED`**. From this how to generate the `AccessToken` in AWS-cognito?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`respondToAuthChallenge`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_RespondToAuthChallenge.html#API_RespondToAuthChallenge_RequestSyntax) method to set the user's new password and log them in. It should also return the `accessToken` for you.

You could do something like this:

```
$result = $this->client->respondToAuthChallenge([
            'ChallengeName' => 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED',
            'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
            'ChallengeResponses' => [
                'USERNAME' => $username,
                'NEW_PASSWORD' => $password,
            ],
            'Session' => $session,
        ]);
```

Comment: Should we add session here

Comment: @imlokeshs I'm not sure. The documentation says it isn't required, but you'll have to test and see whether it's necessary.

Comment: Response is undefined for me.

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions?

Comment: Yes. It says Session need to be added.

Comment: Cool, then just add it to the request array, e.g. `'Session' => $session,`. Updated my answer to include it too.

Comment: so we have create our own UI for setting new password?

Answer (score 0):

You need to respond this challenge (respondToAuthChallenge) using the session returned by adminInitiateAuth method. This session is a key to respond because the user at this time not is logged yet and is valid for 3 minutes. After that, you will reveive (if the session is valid) the RefreshToken, AccessToken and IdToken.